# How to use a custom font for \mathfrak?

Tags: math-fonts

I am playing around with different math fonts, and currently I am using:
`\usepackage[amsthm, libertine, varbb]{newtxmath}` which gives me some nice fonts for math, `\mathcal`, `\mathbb` and `\mathscr`. The only thing I don't like is the result of `\mathfrak`. I think I found some nice font files online, let's call it `MyFrakFont.otf`, but I couldn't figure out how to load this font. I am using `babel` and `fontspec`, none of which seems capable of loading the font for `\mathfrak` (I guess these packages don't deal with math fonts), so I am stuck. How can I use a custom font file for the `\mathfrak` command?

Answer (score 1):

Define a font face and redefine `\mathfrak` to use the font by means of `\text`.

Replace Lucida Blackletter OT, used just by way of example, with your preferred Fraktur font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[amsthm, libertine, varbb]{newtxmath}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\newfontface{\preferredfraktur}{Lucida Blackletter OT}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\mathfrak}{m}{\text{\normalfont\preferredfraktur#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

$a+\mathcal{B}+\mathbb{C}+\mathscr{D}+\mathfrak{x}+\mathfrak{Z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenType fonts with `unicode-math`, although you’ll need to replace `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` with an OpenType math font, such as Libertinus Math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
% Unifraktur Maguntia is available at https://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/maguntia.html#comparison
% Stylistic Set 1 has the modern forms.
\setmathfont{Unifraktur Maguntia}[range=frak, StylisticSet=1, Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathfont{Euler Math}[range={cal, bfcal}, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}

$a+\mathcal{B}+\mathbb{C}+\mathscr{D}+\mathfrak{x}+\mathfrak{Z}$

\end{document}
```

Since Unicode only defines one script alphabet, you’ll need to load an alphabet with `range=cal` or `range=scr` to get both `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`.

[image: ![Libertinus Math + Unifraktur Maguntia font sample]